Couchbase Lite Replication code 139 C# .NET
I am attempting to setup replication between a .NET (8.0.403) C# application using Couchbase Lite (3.2.0), and a Couchbase Server + Couchbase Sync Gateway running in docker containers on the same machine (M3 Mac). The replication code is as follows:
// Get the database (and create it if it doesn't exist)
var database = new Database("mydb");
var collection = database.GetDefaultCollection();

// Create replicator to push and pull changes to and from
var targetEndpoint = new URLEndpoint(new Uri("ws://localhost:4984/audit"));
var replConfig = new ReplicatorConfiguration(targetEndpoint);
replConfig.AddCollection(database.CreateCollection("projects", "audit"));

// Add authentication
replConfig.Authenticator = new BasicAuthenticator("user@fake.com", "passwordFake");
replConfig.Continuous = true;
replConfig.ReplicatorType = ReplicatorType.PushAndPull;

// Create replicator
var replicator = new Replicator(replConfig);
replicator.AddChangeListener(OnReplicatorUpdate);

try {
    replicator.Start(); //THIS LINE FAILS
} catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}

However the call to replicator.Start() results in the following error message:
Process finished with exit code 139. with no other error or warning logs and the application quits. I am running the console app via Jetbrains Rider and dotnet run.
This same code and docker setup works on a Windows 10 machine.
Additionally, after changing this code to connect to a Couchbase Capella instance, it continues to exit with the same error on Mac, but succeeds on Windows
This same simple application also works on my M3 Mac when written in Java rather than .NET C#
How can I have the replication succeed on a M3 Mac.
